# Issue with testing for presence of links with rspec and assert_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm currently in the process of learning rspec by rewriting all the Rails Tutorial (Hartl) tests in rspec. I'm having an issue with testing for the presence of links using rspec. **For whatever reason, my test fails when it seems like it definitely should pass; there are clearly links to the specified url, but it always says there are 0 found.**

The following is my rspec code to test for the presence of two links to the root path:

```
require 'spec_helper'
require 'rails_helper'

describe StaticPagesController, :type => :view do

  it "root path contains all expected links" do 
    render :template => 'static_pages/home'
    puts response.body
    assert_template 'static_pages/home'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", "/", count: 2
  end
end
```

The following is my error message:

```
waynesun95:~/workspace/sample_app (advanced-login) $ bundle exec rspec
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is outdated/buggy. (To disable warnings, set RUBY_DEP_GEM_SILENCE_WARNINGS=1)
RubyDep: WARNING: Your Ruby is: 2.3.0 (buggy). Recommendation: install 2.3.1.
<div class="center jumbotron">  
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>
  <h2>
    This is the home page for the 
    <a href="http://www.railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/signup">Sign up now!</a>
</div>

<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Rails logo" src="/assets/rails-c094bc3a4bf50e5bb477109e5cb0d213af27ad75b481c4df249f50974dbeefe6.png" /></a>
......F

Failures:

  1) StaticPagesController root path contains all expected links
     Failure/Error: assert_select "a[href=?]", "/", count: 2

     Minitest::Assertion:
       Expected exactly 2 elements matching "a[href="/"]", found 0..
       Expected: 2
         Actual: 0
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:139:in `assert'
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/minitest-5.9.0/lib/minitest/assertions.rb:174:in `assert_equal'
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:278:in `assert_size_match!'
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:175:in `block in assert_select'
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `tap'
     # ./.bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rails-dom-testing-1.0.7/lib/rails/dom/testing/assertions/selector_assertions.rb:174:in `assert_select'
     # ./spec/users_signup_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.47062 seconds (files took 12.61 seconds to load)
7 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/users_signup_spec.rb:6 # StaticPagesController root path contains all expected links
```

The error message says that it found 0 elements matching a[href="/"]. However, upon inspection of the page that I am testing on, when I right click and 'inspect element' on the element that links to the root path, it is clearly linking to "/" (highlighted in picture below).
 [highlighted "Home" link clearly links to the path "/"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5b5w.png)

Furthermore, I know I am on the correct template/view, because when I remove the assert_select line and only leave the render and assert_template lines, the code passes without a problem (further justification of this is that I get an error when I change the path in assert_template).

I have no idea what is going on. It seems like it should be passing the test but it is not, and nothing I try seems to work. Any help is very appreciated!

Comment: Add `puts response.body` after `render :template => 'static_pages/home'` and update your question with the output

Comment: Just updated. However I was also testing all the links on this page (I just didn't include those assert_selects in the code and output), and the 'Sign Up Now!' link also outputted as having 0 occurences

Comment: I wanted to see output from `puts response.body` command. The actual response generated during test

Comment: is this using capybarra?

Comment: I included the output of the puts command in the error message.

Comment: And no I am not using capybara.